# Maximum value of the product given a linear function of gradient k

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives

I have been trying to solve the problem below and have a hit a bit of roablock. So I was wondering if anyone could give me some hints or a small nudge in the right direction to help me come to the solution.

```
Two real numbers x and y are such that kx + y = 100, where k is a positive constant. Find, 
in terms of k, the maximum value of the product of the two numbers.
```

So far I have derived it to get$ \frac {dy} {dx} = -k$ and substituted the point $(0,100)$ to try and get a value of $k$ but this has been fruitless.

Any comments or hints about my current way of thinking or some ideas to consider would be greatly appreciated. I must also add that I do not want a complete solution to this problem. This would remove the challenge and fun for me in trying to solve this question.

Comment: try to express $y$ in terms of $x$ and $k$ and then form the product